# Karate: Validate JSON response variable is null or greater than today's date

Tags: karate

JSON response is as below

```
{
    "totalElements": 3,
    "content": [
        {
            "goal": [
                {
                    "id": "911",
                    "subject": {
                        "reference": "Patient/01051992H",
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "startDate": "2022-06-30T15:54:07.572Z"
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "measure": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                                    "code": "85354-9"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "detail": [
                            {
                                "comparator": "<=",
                                "value": 110.0,
                                "unit": "mm[Hg]",

                            }
                        ],
                        "due": {
                            "dueDate": "2022-07-04T07:04:45.718Z"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "913",
                    "subject": {
                        "identifier": null,
                        "reference": "Patient/01051992H",
                        "display": null
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "startDate": "2022-06-30T15:59:08.803Z"
                    },
                    "target": {
                        "measure": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "system": "urn:iso:std:iso:11073:10101",
                                    "code": "MDC_RATIO_MASS_BODY_LEN_SQ"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "detail": [
                            {
                                "comparator": ">=",
                                "value": 35.0,
                                "unit": "kg/m2",
                                "system": "https://ucum.org",
                                "code": "kg/m2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "due": {
                            "dueDate": null
                        }
                    }
               }   
    ]
}
```

need to validate whether startdate is less than or equal to current date time and
dueDate is null or greater than current date time

Kindly help me in understanding how to validate if "response.content[*].goal[*].target[*].due.dueDate" is null or > current date time

Tried below, but its not working

```
Then match response.content[0].goal[0].start == {startDate: '#? _ <= todaysdate' }
Then match response.content[*].goal[*].target[*].due == [{dueDate: '#? _ > todaysdate' || dueDate: '#null'}]
```

Comment: I have linked to an answer that should answer all your questions. if you still have doubts, please ask a new question and this time please keep your example simple and minimal: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example